# Cannot import and export classes

Tags: javascript

I am making a webpage with glitch.com, but this error keeps appearing:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

This is the code from where the error appears:

```
import {Unit} from "./Unit.js";
```

This is how I export Unit: (Unit is a class)

```
export {Unit};
```

There aren't any errors in the `Unit` file.

EDIT: Just for reference, when I go to "Inspect" and then "Sources" I don't see the Unit file, could this be the reason?

Comment: Seems like the environment your are using doesn't understand module syntax.

Comment: Welp, time to go with the oldschool way

Answer (score 0):

You don't need curly brackets around the exported class
    export default Unit;

You shouldn't need them either in the import statement if Unit is the only class you're exporting in Unit.js

```
import Unit from '/Unit.js';
```

Comment: Then the glitch editor starts screaming at me "Unexpected token" and VSC screams "Declaration or statement expected."

Comment: It might be because "The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module"."